# find the smallest integer N, such that

Tags: c#, math, inequality

I am stuck for quite a while now on the following task:

find the smallest integer N, such that A^N < N!

I want to do this in C# and A can be so big that there is no type that can store the results. I also know that this can be solved without actually calculating A^N and N! but I have absolutely no clue how to do this...

Comment: There is a type that can store the results and its name is ['BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0).

Comment: "I also know that this can be solved without actually calculating A^N and N! but I have absolutely no clue how to do this". Then that's what you need to find out and that is not a programming problem. Solve the maths problem first, which is nothing to do with us. When it comes time to implement the logic in code, then we can help you if you run into an actual issue.

Comment: BigInteger is no option hence A will be a double and can't find a "BigDouble" or "BigFloat" :(

Comment: Not sure why BigInteger is not an option. It's available in .NET Standard, so every implementation of C# should support it.

Comment: Yes but I need floating point numbers.

Comment: Why do you need floating point numbers? Data is stored as an estimation.

Comment: Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for such a question?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid checking all possible values of N, you can estimate it's value using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

```
A^N < N!
ln(A^N) < ln(N!)
N*ln(A) < N*ln(N) - N + some small addition
ln(A) < ln(N) - 1 + some small addition
ln(A)+1 < ln(N)
ln(A*e) < ln(N)
N > A*e
```

So get initial value of `N = A*e` (`Math.E` in c#), and you need to check rather small range of N's to find exact value

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Very interesting...
But I not sure if that helps me in this situation :( Lets assume A = 3 then the smallest N for N > A * e to be true is 9 while the smallest N for A^N < N! to be tue is 7

Comment: You see that 9!>3^9 and execute some iterations until n! becomes less than 3^n.  When you have found that N=6 is too small  - result is 7.

Comment: Yeah but N can be so big that I can not calculate N! or A^N :(
1 < A < 10000  resulting in N > 20000 in some cases.

Comment: You have not mentioned `A` range in the question... Use long arithmetics or work with logarithm   - look at `Writing Stirling's series in the form` formula at Wiki page